# Remove and reinstall kubelet and kubectl

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubelet

Somewhere along the way I messed up installation of the kubectl, now I want to reinstall the kubectl and kubelet
But when I checked the syslog I am still gettting the following error:

```
systemd[133926]: kubelet.service: Failed to execute command: No such file or directory
systemd[133926]: kubelet.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/bin/kubelet: No such file or directory
systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

How do i get rid of this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not good to remove kubelet as it's the main components of the node. If you need to remove kubelet, better to remove the node  itself and add back which would most preferred and easy one... Like scale-in and then scale out...

Kubectl.. can done by uninstall package...

For CentOS,

```
yum uninstall -y kubectl
```

Can check and execute command based on specific os distribution...